# Why (char *) is used in write() function in C++?

Tags: c++

```
person pers;
pers.getData();
fstream fs("person.txt", ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary | ios::app);
fs.write((char*)&pers, sizeof(pers));
```

I am trying to be clear why the address of object (&pers) needs to be cast to pointer to character while writing to file?

Comment: because syntax of `write()` requires its first argument to be `char *`

Comment: Thanks for your response! While writing object in binary mode, what happens when the address of object is cast to pointer to char?

Comment: @mangusta: No, it won't treat it as a terminated string. The second argument specifies the number of bytes.

Comment: Is that because binary files are accessed one byte at a time and the size of char is one byte?

Comment: @mangusta: It won't "put `EOF` at the end", whatever that means. It will simply write the specified number of characters to the stream.

Comment: @MikeSeymour ok, this is better: function will treat `pers` as a sequence of chars and will write those chars into the file stream

Comment: @mangusta: Thanks! One more question, sequence of *chars* here means a sequence of bytes? And, why char, because it's one byte and binary file are accessed one byte at a time? Sorry for my naive question! I just wanted to be clear about that.

Comment: @ParanoidAndroid `char` may have different sizes depending on the language, particularly in this case, yes, chars means a sequence of bytes

Answer (score 3):

Because that's how `write` is declared:

```
basic_ostream& write(const char_type* s, streamsize n);
```

It writes an array of characters to the stream. If you want to (ab)use it to write the bytes of some other type, then you'll need a dodgy cast to pretend it's an array of characters.

Personally, I'd use `reinterpret_cast`: it's slightly less dangerous, and more obvious, than a C-style cast.

Comment: Also, writting the bytes of a user-defined type like that could be dangerous if it is not a POD, correct?

Comment: @0x499602D2: Writing is safe. Reading back and trying to reinterpret the bytes as a non-trivial object is dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

because `fstream.write` requires a `char*` as its first argument.

```
ostream& write (const char* s, streamsize n);
```

Comment: No, it doesn't require a string. It requires a pointer to a char, and by design accepts pointers to what cannot be called string by any reasonable definition of "string".