# What does typecasting char* do in read function?

Tags: c++

```
customer c1;
ifstream fin ;
fin.open("savings.txt", ios :: in | ios :: binary) ;
fin.read((char *) & c1, sizeof(customer));
```

I just wanted to be clear what I understood so far from the the last read statement. The read operation reads the required number of bytes (length of customer object) from the position of get pointer, and typecast the address of customer type to pointer to character type and store the read bytes into c1 object. I'd appreciate if anyone could make the process more clear. I took many references but couldn't find the better explanations.

Comment: how the type `customer` is defined ?

Comment: For instance, 

class customer
{
    char name [51] ;
    float balance ;
};

Comment: and I assume that there is no `overload` for the `&` operator in that class ?

Comment: Why would the cast be any different from how it's used in `fs.write(...);`, [which you asked about yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909334/why-char-is-used-in-write-function-in-c)? If you have trouble with the answers there (which I can understand), you should probably ask for clarification there, or edit that question.

Comment: @hvd: Yes, I should have asked there, my mistake. I thought to start a new question as earlier question was on writing and this one is for reading, although the parameters are similar.

Answer (score 3):

The cast tells the compiler that the address of c1 should be considered to actually point to data of type `char`.  It's done because the `read` function expects the first argument o be of that type - it's designed towork with "binary" data and accesses/uses that data based purely on the starting address and number of bytes.

Comment: And in this case, `char*` doesn't semantically mean a pointer-to-a-character, but rather the byte interpretation of `c1`, which is represented the same way.

Comment: @MooseBoys and how do you call the fact that `c1` is an instance of a class and not something that can simply be correctly interpreted as `char *` ?

Comment: @user2485710 It should be able to be correctly interpreted as `char*`, albeit maybe in a not technically compiler-portable way.  Given the definition of `customer`, most compilers will end up interpreting `&c1` as `c1.name`.

Comment: @user2485710 `customer` is a POD type (given `class customer { char name [51] ; float balance ; };`, from the comments on the question), and the bytes that make up a POD type can be written to a file and read back without any problem.

Comment: @MooseBoys While `(char *) &c1` and `c1.name` will compare equal -- not just on most, but on all conforming implementations, as it is required by the language -- compilers can and if I recall correctly sometimes do treat them differently in terms of whether the bytes that make up `balance` can be accessed. From `(char *) &c1`, I know it's valid, and it will definitely work on all systems. From `c1.name`, I'm not sure if it's valid, and if it is valid, then I know that some implementations have bugs in that area.

Comment: @hvd "without any problem" well it's `C++` not `C with objects`; based on what you are saying that this behaviour is even "ok" with actual implementations of the language ? That's just bad bad code.

Comment: @user2485710 C++ has different rules for different types. For this type, it's okay, not just accepted by real-world implementations, but permitted by the standard as well.

Comment: hwd's right - casting to char is the only conversion which is guaranteed legal in this situation - and while the padding is unspecified by the Standard the size() includes it such that read() will read padding bytes too... assuming the objects were written with the same padding, things work.  It's not just nasty hackery - a lot of systems rely on C and C++ programs being able to handle memory content in this way for their efficiency, including OSes and communications libraries.

Comment: @TonyD and all: Many thanks for your response! So, after reading the comment, what I understood is that, the (char*)&c1 in the first parameter of read converts just the type of address (customer*) to (char*) before it writes the read bytes from the file to the address of c1. Is that right?

Comment: @ParanoidAndroid: yes, that's right.  The code could have said `fin.read(c1.name, sizeof(customer));` instead in this case, because the first field happens to be a character array, but that would be more fragile (e.g. breaks when another field is inserted at the start of the structure) and potentially confusing.